# “An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions” when accessing localhost from inside an Azure Function

Tags: java, azure, azure-function-app, opentripplanner

**Disclaimer**:

It's a cliche but it works on my machine(!)

**Context**:

Http Triggered Azure Function App Running on Windows With a "Free Tier" option.

**Details**:

I have an Azure Function App that host and runs a JAR file that spins up a Grizzly server which basically serves a JAVA app hosted in localhost:8080
The function app manages to start up the JAVA app by simply using.
The JAVA app is called Open Trip Planner and it runs in a Grizzly server.

```
 Process.Start(javaPath, "<<JAR OPTIONS HERE>>");
```

- Up until here it works in both my machine and Azure.

Then I run a separate thread that checks the App has started:

```
                  while (true)
                  {
                      Thread.Sleep(10000);
                      try
                      {
                          var result = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:8080"); 
// <-- The above fails in Azure but not in my local machine.
                      }
                      catch (Exception ex)
                      {
                          log.LogError(ex.Message);
                      }
                  }
```

The exception is:
"“An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions”

[image: Azure Function App Logs]

**Exception Details**:

> **Exception Type**:
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
>
> **Message**
>
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions
>
> **StackTrace**
>
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1
>   creationTask)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
>   HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
>   disposeCts)    at
>   ScoreAddressFunction.ScoreAddress.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in
>   /home/vsts/work/1/s/ScoreAddressFunction/ScoreAddressFunction/ScoreAddress.cs:line
>   85

**However**, it works if I change the URL to something like "https://www.google.com" which makes me think this is not caused by a limited number of available sockets as a read in other answers.

**Question**:

Is there something wrong -conceptually- with trying to access localhost (or 127.0.0.1) from inside an Azure Function App?
Am I missing some technical / security restriction?

One of my concerns is that I am facing this issue from a wrong conceptual point of view. However, the process I run needs **A LOT of memory** and having it working on an Azure Function App for the time I need it would be awesome otherwise it will be very expensive.

Comment: Stack trace please.

Comment: My best guess is that you were blocked by some sort of security policy configured in the JVM in the server side. Read this and research about it and Azure Function App: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19118-01/n1.sprovsys41/817-4820/6mkaodgb5/index.html

Comment: That would violate the very basic assumption of AF based on consumption plan (free tier) - you pay for execution time (CPU cycles). When you spawn a separate process there is no way to start the "billing" timer for the new process, as there is no AF trigger. Therefore I'd assume that it would not work under the consumption plan (as MS would not be able to properly bill you). Theoretically, it could work under a premium plan, but the lack of a proper AF framework (trigger) in the spawned server is still against the very AF concept.